# integer to byte in Java and C++

Tags: java, c++

In my C++ code, I need to convert an `int` and put it inside a byte. I represent a byte using a `char`. 
In my java code, I should read this `byte` (it is sent over the network), and I should get the appropriate `int` from that byte (the one that I sent).

I should mention that this byte is less than 15, so one byte would be sufficient for it

However, the Java code is reading negative numbers in some attempts, and when I tried other ways it gave me totally different numbers. I suspect it is a problem of big/little endian.

What I've tried:

```
// C++
char bytes[255];
bytes[0] = myInt; // attempt 1
bytes[0] = myInt & 0xFF; // attempt 2
// ... send the byte array over the network

// JAVA
// receive the byte
int readInt = bytes[0]; //attempt 1
int readInt = bytes[0] & 0xFF; // attempt2
```

How should I properly do this, given that the two applications (C++ side and JAVA side) will run on the same ubuntu machine?

Comment: sounds like it might be an endian issue.

Comment: If the length of what you're writing and reading is just one byte, then it's not endian issue.  If value is definitely less than 15, then I would think attempt one should work, attempt 2 would run into endian issues.

Comment: What does your debugger say is in bytes[] - because otherwise the best we can do is speculate?

Comment: Using attempt1, I do in C++ `bytes[0] = 7`, I print the int that I got in java using `readInt = bytes[0];` and what it prints is that `readInt = -32`

Comment: I guess the obvious question would be what is "send the byte array over the network" doing. Getting -32 from 7 isn't even remotely correct. I think you are having problems in your network code.

Comment: Forget about converting ints into bytes for the moment. Just work on sending data in bytes and receiving data back in bytes. Just bytes everywhere. No ints to confuse yourself with. Once you've figured out the cause, you can then start converting to/from int.

Answer (score 1):

Further edit: `int readInt = bytes[0] & 0xFF` should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    byte b = (byte) i;
    int j = b & 0xFF;
    System.out.println("The byte is " + b + " and the int is " + j);
}
```

Gives:

```
The byte is 0 and the int is 0
The byte is 1 and the int is 1
...
The byte is 126 and the int is 126
The byte is 127 and the int is 127
The byte is -128 and the int is 128
The byte is -127 and the int is 129
...
The byte is -2 and the int is 254
The byte is -1 and the int is 255
```

Edit (after comment above):  `7 = 0000 0111 and -32 = 1110 0000 (= 224 as int)` The issue appears to be some kind of mirroring flip.

and `170 = 1010 1010 (= -86 as Java byte)` which doesn't make sense to me because how did 3 on bits turn into 4 and spread out.

Comment: This have given me that `readInt = 170`, while I put `7` at the C++ side

Answer (score 1):

Note: it's *never* an endian issue. Only if you work low level or make your own *arrays of bytes* to represent one number, it may be an endian issue.

It is only one byte now, so no endian issue.

<strike>Try to use unsigned int.</strike>

Comment: Have you seen unsigned int in Java...? I can't see how your answer helps OP in any way...

Comment: I can not post comments still and the comments on the other answer about endianness could lead to error. I know it is not an answer, but could not write anywhere else, sorry.

Comment: You can make comments everywhere. This privilege requires 50 reputation while you have 76. Remember that you might lose this privilege if you keep posting answers like this...